# Please link the MathJax help to the Meta.Math.SE tutorial

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, formatting

The Ask a Question page shown to new users contains a lot of guidance, including a link to MathJax help:

> [image]

Now, there are [strong UI reasons why this link is nowhere near as useful as we'd hope](https://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/), but we can at least make it point to something that's actually useful. It currently points to [this tutorial](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/), which looks like this

> [image]

and which is nowhere near a useful resource. Despite the claims in a [recent attempt](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/) to duplicate a bunch of work and create a local tutorial of limited usefulness, we do in fact have a long-standing go-to tutorial for MathJax, over on the Mathematics meta site,

> [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
>
> [image: MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference]

The equivalent link over on Maths.SE links to their tutorial. Since we're already linking off-site for this, why don't we also link to theirs?

---

This has a fair amount of support. Is it something the mods can change? Do we need to contact the community team? Have already done so? If so, have said whether it's feasible or not?

Comment: This is one the SE team will have to handle, as moderators don't have the ability to edit that section.

Comment: @David sure, but this is still the right place to raise this.

Comment: I find that it's also been [proposed on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-the-tutorial-on-mathematics), quite a while ago in fact. I'll see if I can get some higher-up eyes on this.

Comment: Ok, this is my bad for not [writing up the process on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-a-more-specific-guide/288209#288209) before now. tl;dr: figure out what you want the link to be, post feature request, then ping me once it's clear no one's gonna fight about it.