# Awarding Informed Badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think the [Informed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/121/informed) Badge must not be given so easily.

Before giving the informed badge, newcomers should not only be briefed about basic rules and regulations of Physics SE , but also :-

1. Be given more information about the system of badges and reputation.
2. Be given a short article on using Mathjax and Latex.
   ( I have seen many newcomers not being aware of these things )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have very little control over this. Physics Stack Exchange is part of a network of [160+ sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). All the sites share a common engine, so it *is* possible to request and obtain site-specific changes to the common behaviour, but they need to be very well justified.

The place to request changes to the engine is at the overarching meta site, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), where it is easier to get the attention of the community team and the developers. Our meta site is better for issues specific to this site and its community.

Frankly, I don't think it's particularly problematic. The entry-level badges are awarded easily as an incentive for new users to explore the site's features, by adding some fake internet sugar on top. In the grand scheme of things, though, it's not that important.

---

On the MathJax side, though, you're right, but that's not quite the right approach - I advocated [this one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/please-link-the-mathjax-help-to-the-meta-math-se-tutorial) earlier <s>but it's not yet implemented</s> and it just went live.

Comment: Try it on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Are you directing me to advocate for your proposal on MSE? As I said, I think the current situation is pretty much fine.

Comment: Not that  , I meant  , why don't you try your proposal on MSE ?

Comment: @RahulKumar Because it is a site-specific issue, and it is implemented by getting the moderators to contact the developer team once there is a community consensus that it should be implemented. As I said, it has not been implemented *yet*.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty FWIW, the SE team does occasionally scan site metas for popular feature requests and bug reports, and anyone can [contact them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact) about these things. So you (general) don't _have_ to go through the mods. The advantage of doing so is that it's a little harder for them to ignore us.