# Link to meta page for guide to MathJax commands under text fields (specifically for user agent mobile)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax

Wouldn't it be helpful to provide a link under the text box, shown while asking questions or writing answers, to the meta page dealing with MathJax commands: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  for the **mobile site** also?

It is not only difficult but also tiresome to find out the MathJax commands for each and every math formulae, and one has to either store the above link in the bookmarks, or find it out somehow, because it is not always possible for one to remember all the commands.

Moreover, new comers accessing the site from mobile know nothing about this, and that is why under most questions posted by a new comer, we have to post comments like "Please use MathJax to format the equations" or edit it ourselves.

This new feature, if added, will not only help the new ones, but also the others, because sometimes one may forget the commands, and then it is a whole lot of exercise to find the meta page again.

I request this feature specifically for **mobile agent**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please link the MathJax help to the Meta.Math.SE tutorial](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/please-link-the-mathjax-help-to-the-meta-math-se-tutorial) (which has already been implemented).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm requesting specifically for the **mobile site**, as it is always not possible to access the site from desktop agent using browsers in smartphone.

Comment: My standard advice for writing MathJax on mobile-device keyboards is: don't. It's always going to be painful, and the lack of a link to the tutorial is a very small fraction of the friction in writing math on the mobile site. Notice that the mobile site has a *much* cleaner interface - the only thing that's left is the image upload button. Why should math be singled out over, say, bulk code and quote indents? Can you provide a mock-up and show that it's doable without cluttering the interface?

Comment: Also: as a concern for new users, I don't think any significant fraction are coming in via the mobile site (which means that individuals who find this frustrating can just solve this with a bookmark). That's pure unfounded intuition, though, so I've [asked for hard numbers on the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296239/what-fraction-of-new-users-come-in-through-the-mobile-site-and-the-ios-and-andro) so we can see how important that stream is.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses [v1 of the question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/9877/1), which asked about the desktop version.

---

If you mean this link,

> [image]

it [already links to the meta.math.se tutorial](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/please-link-the-mathjax-help-to-the-meta-math-se-tutorial).

If you mean something else, then you should clarify where else you would like those links to be placed. However, if your goal is helping first-time users who have never used the site, keep in mind that [user myopia](https://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/) is a very real thing. Unless you can work out a way to put that link somewhere in this area,

> [image]

it will be invisible to most new users. And, if you *do* want to put it there, then I would also ask how you're going to make it unintrusive for the large population of users who already know how to format their posts.