# Add a link and hint to use MathJax to the new question dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, mathjax

We like to see MathJax used on Physics SE for equations, but at present when you are typing in a new question I think there is no on-screen link to the [MathJax  "guide"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or a reminder to use MathJax for equations.

There is an [old Q&A on Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9880/104964) which says that this has been implemented, but it's not there *now* so must have been removed during site updates.

It might help to have something like this added to the new question edit page:

- Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations in questions.

On Physics SE this would ideally be prominently above the edit box in bold maybe.

Certainly if we don't even mention MathJax to new users until after they've posted we're just asking for having to repeat the same thing in comments over and over.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344706) fit the bill?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Almost.  I'd still prefer a bit of prominent text to  let (particularly new) users know we have Mathjax and expect it to be used.  Thanks for the link to that post - I'll vote it up anyway and maybe add a comment there.  Do you think I should close this question here or is it still useful ?

Comment: No, please keep it open - it is precisely these threads (and their score!) that the dev team uses to weigh what features to prioritise.

Comment: Very related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12755/258881

Comment: Extremely related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12935/please-make-mathjax-formatting-more-discoverable-to-new-users?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Sorry this took so long to get back to, but want to let you know this is on our list to address. When we have more updates, we'll update this post with more.

Comment: @JonChan Thanks for this info.  Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be useful to have the MathJax help link (at Math Meta) in the **Your Answer** menu bar in addition to the Question Dialog.  It would help both new and experienced users who are giving answers have that resource while constructing an answer.

It might also help new users to realize that they should use MathJax rather than taking photos of textbooks to supplement an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've just got a ping from colleagues that the link was added. Please take a look

[image]

We hope it is what you've requested!